# Taking vertices and using point to path creates a mess, how can I snap the lines to roads?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, snapping, vertices, points-to-line

I’ve tried points to path (and various other processing tools) however I end up with this:

[image]

When really it should look more like this line string

[image]

(without the gaps separating chunks of road here and there) and of course in blue). How can I make the points to path in QGIS not look like a mess and snap to the roads?

Edit 1: Regarding @barrycarter query: I intend to have one path like you would have a route in a gpx but on a larger scale, I then intend to export the “route”, extract the coordinates and use them to draw something in an app on a gps device.

Edit 2:  I do not wish for the jumping from all the way in the east to the west to happen, hence the question of them snapping to roads therefore forcing it to follow a proper route.

Edit 3: A bonus would be it choosing the simplest route but that is not necessary so long as it just sticks to the roads.

Comment: Wait. Are you taking all your points and creating a single multipath? I'm sure you want one multipath per road.

Comment: @barrycarter updated post in answer to your question

Comment: So you're intentionally connecting the end of one road to the start of another?

Comment: Yes, unless it is a dead end in which case it could double back, I just don’t want it to go off road basically.

Comment: OK, but are these roads connected to each other? Right now, you're jumping from the end of a road in Maine to the start of a road in California.

Comment: I am editing post now as cannoy discuss further in comments it seems.

Comment: It'll eventually move us to chat, which shouldn't be an issue

Comment: I do not have enough rep for that, sorry.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137343/lines-across-america

Comment: Give me a minute to figure out how to use it.

Comment: It will not allow it, Discord possible? Rep too low.

Comment: gimme a sec....

Comment: I think you have to create a chat account-- when you click on my link does it give you an option to do that? I'd like to keep the discussion here if possible

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Comment: Well, we tried. Google Hangouts me at carter.barry@gmail.com

Comment: That is video chat? No offence but am not comfortable sharing my face with a stranger albiet a helpful one.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't see this. It has a video chat feature, but we can talk via text. I never use the video feature (just deny permission to your mic/camera if it asks)

Comment: @barrycarter Good news, it seems I can now talk in chat according to my profile info, it’s late here however so tomorrow may be better if you can, if not perhaps next weekend then it may be easier to discuss the solution to my question.

Comment: I'll be intermittent on https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137343/lines-across-america today, but think we can get this figured out